# Accessing javascript variables within Django HTML

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models

I'm adding data to include in a form in Chart.js in Django. I originally had:

```
home_data.push({x: "{{transaction.transaction_time.month}}/{{transaction.transaction_time.day}} {{transaction.transaction_time.hour}}:{{transaction.transaction_time.minute}}", y: {{transaction.price}}})
```

But now what I'm trying to do is adjust the transaction.transaction_time value in order to do this I want to assign it to a separate variable to later get the value of that variable. Here's what I tried doing:

```
var transaction_adjusted = {{transaction.transaction_time}}

home_data.push({x: "{{transaction_adjusted.month}}/{{transaction_adjusted.day}} {{transaction_adjusted.hour}}:{{transaction_adjusted.minute}}", y: {{transaction.price}}})
```

In my console window: I see that the values evaluated such as {{transaction_adjusted.month}} evaluate to nothing. Why is this?

Comment: Might be worth looking at the `json_script` tag for passing context variables to JS https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm using class-based views and use get_context_data to pass values into HTML (the first code snippet works perfectly). How would you suggest using json_script here? Like what would the key-value pair be?

Answer (score 0):

The [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag can be used to assign a new context variable as the result of a function call or attribute access

```
{% with transaction_adjusted=transaction.transaction_time %}
    var transaction_adjusted = {{transaction_adjusted}}

    home_data.push({x: "{{transaction_adjusted.month}}/{{transaction_adjusted.day}} {{transaction_adjusted.hour}}:{{transaction_adjusted.minute}}", y: {{transaction.price}}})
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it. I have a similar related question that I was wondering if you knew the answer to. The value that transaction_adjusted has is a python datetime object. If I wanted to subtract 5 hours from it what would be the best way to do it? It's hard to deal with python objects in a javascript. In the terminal the datetime object looks like a string in the form: "Jan. 8, 2021, 8:10 p.m."

Comment: In Python you would subtract a `datetime.timedelta` object from your datetime object: `datetime_obj - datetime.timedelta(hours=5)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: right, what about within the script? or is there not a way to do that within the js script on the html template?